# BigQuery: Replace a partition (drop + insert) atomically through DML

Tags: google-bigquery

We have huge tables with huge partitions. In some scenarios, we want to replace an entire partition: drop the partition and insert fresh data into the same partition, and we need to do it **atomically** and through **DML**.

One approach is to use MERGE, deleting everything from the table filtering by the partition and then inserting new data atomically. But in this approach, the DELETE statement scans the entire partition and we want to avoid this.

Question:
¿Is there a way to DROP a partition (not DELETE it, DROP it), and after that, INSERT new data into the same partition, atomically, with DML?

I want to achieve the same result of this command:

```
bq load --replace "dataset.PartitionedTable\$20230620" ./data.csv
```

but in DML and changing data.csv by a SELECT statement.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a good solution to your question since you already have the table, but if you use partition as the table_suffix, you can do it easily via create replace statements.

To be able to do it, you should have different tables for each partition like:

- PartitionedTable_20230620
- PartitionedTable_20230621
- PartitionedTable_20230622

So when you want to override a partition, you can use this query

```
create or replace table dataset.PartitionedTable_20230620 as 
select ...
```

If you want to query all the table, you can use table wildcars like:

```
select * 
from `dataset.PartitionedTable_*`
where _table_suffix between '20230620' and '20230622' -- this is optional, but always good to optimize
```

This solution also gives you extra space for partitioning and clustering. For example, you can use userid for partitioning and region for clustering, which will lower your costs as well.

Comment: thanks, this solution actually solves what I posted via DML.. but I prefer to avoid wildcard tables